# Issue with the Multiaction Controller in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a jsp page from which i have to pass the control to the next page.
And i am using Multiaction Controller for that but its giving me an error 404.

My JSP File is

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"  action="registerSuccessControl.htm" commandName="register" >
        <strong> <label> <label> <label>
                        <div align="center">Registeration</div>
                </label></strong> <label></label>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <p>
            First Name <input type="text" name="textfield" accesskey="1"
                tabindex="1" /> <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;Last Name</label> <strong> <input type="text"
                name="textfield3" />
            </strong>
        </p>
```

and this is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/registerSuccessControl.htm")
    public ModelAndView registerSuccessControl(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register,BindingResult brResult,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("RegisterSuccesssControl called");
        //logger.debug("Registration Page Accessed at "+new Date());
        System.out.println("I am In registerSuccess");

        RegistrationValidator uValidator=new RegistrationValidator();       
        uValidator.validate(register,brResult);     
        HashMap<String, BindingResult> resultMap = new HashMap<String, BindingResult>();
        if(brResult.hasErrors()){           
            resultMap.put("errors", errors);
            return new ModelAndView("Register",resultMap);
        }
        else 
            return new ModelAndView("Firm");
}
```

I have other request handled in same controller and its working fine, but its not working for this link.

Comment: Does your class extend from `MultiActionController`? Which Spring Version do you use 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: @Ralph yes bro i am extending Multiaction COntroller and version used is 3.x

Comment: It looks like you use the annotation style for the controllers, so I do not see any reason to extend from `MultiActionController`

Comment: @Ralph i was using annotation as well as extending the class. Problem Solved